# Efficiently merging and reducing polygons with Python

Tags: python, google-maps, svg, geometry, polygon

What's the most efficient way, preferably in Python, to merge and simplify several  polygons into the equivalent shape but using much fewer polygons?

[image: polygon reduction]

I'm attempting to graph zip code regions, as defined by [US Census data](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/ZCTA5/2010/tl_2010_42_zcta510.zip) on a Google Map. Using Django's excellent [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) framework and a hack I made to the [django-census-places](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-census-places) app, I now have thousands of zips and lat/lng vectors describing their region in my database.

I've written some basic Python to export the vectors and render the Javascript to  draw selected zips on a Google Map. However, the problem I've run into is that it's horribly slow, as even a single zip code can contain thousands of polygons. I can preprocess this output to JSON and cache it, but even then it takes the browser a few minutes to load all the triangles, most of which are redundant since I'm only interested in the overall outline of several zip codes.

Note, this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386906/efficient-algorithms-to-merge-polygons), but not the same. I've not concerned with overlapping polygons, since I believe there are no overlaps.

Edit: [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23365/combining-adjacent-polygons-sharing-a-similar-trait-into-1-polygon-arcgis) question also appears very similar.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out one of the several features in GeoDjango is a full range of boolean polygon operators. All I have to do is call union() on each of my  MultiPolygon objects to get the MultiPolygon describing the entire region. The reduction in number of points is an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

To merge polygons I suggest you need to perform a [boolean **union** operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons). I'm not sure how you'd do this in Python, but since you've also mentioned JavaScript, there's an excellent JavaScript translation of my Clipper library (written in Delphi, C++ and C#) [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/).

There's also an online demo [**here**](http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.1/main_demo.html) which very nicely shows the capabilities of the clipping library.

Comment: On the demo page, are the numbers under the "Time" heading in seconds, or minutes?

Comment: I would guess milliseconds. Clear the benchmarks and perform another clip operation. The operation happens much faster than the eye can see so it's definitely not seconds or minutes :).